# Convert List<string> to StringCollection

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, string

I need the above feature because I can only store StringCollection to Settings, not List of strings.

How does one convert List into StringCollection?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

How about:

```
StringCollection collection = new StringCollection();
collection.AddRange(list.ToArray());
```

Alternatively, avoiding the intermediate array (but possibly involving more reallocations):

```
StringCollection collection = new StringCollection();
foreach (string element in list)
{
    collection.Add(element);
}
```

Converting back is easy with LINQ:

```
List<string> list = collection.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

Comment: Just wondering, why would avoiding intermediate array be recommended?

Comment: @l46kok: All other things being equal, avoiding extra intermediate copies is always recommended. In this case, however, it's not obvious which approach is more efficient (due to the extra reallocations) and probably not important anyway, given the typical size of a settings collection.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: Always? I wouldn't go with that. The first code is clearly simpler, and given that (as you say) it's probably not important, I'd stick with the possibly-less-efficient-but-more-obvious approach.

Comment: @JonSkeet: You're right. I included that in "All other things being equal," but I wasn't as clear as I should have been.

Answer (score 5):

Use  `List.ToArray()` which will convert List to an Array which you can use to add values in your `StringCollection`.

```
StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();
sc.AddRange(mylist.ToArray());

//use sc here.
```

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.addrange.aspx)

Comment: Why are you doing `string[] str = mylist.ToArray();` when you could just do `sc.AddRange(mylist.ToArray());`?

Comment: @john: To tell him what would `mylist.ToArray()` returns and `AddRange()` takes.

Comment: Isn't that obvious by using `.ToArray();`?

Comment: @john What a waste of voting rights. Jon's answer and his answer are practically same and still he gets 2 downvotes...

Comment: @AmitMittal: I am sure OP asked this question because he wont be making StringCollection for fun. He will be using it in further code. and i have also done that.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I was being Sarcastic :)

Comment: @AmitMittal: He is THE JONSKEET. The one with ~half-a-million reputation.

Comment: It is not Jon's fault..he has earned it :) but my point was that a correct solution (your solution is correct) should not get downvotes and more importantly you should not modify the correct solutions just to appease the downvoter..

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension method to convert an `IEnumerable<string>` to a `StringCollection`. It works the same way as the other answers, just wraps it up.

```
public static class IEnumerableStringExtensions
{
    public static StringCollection ToStringCollection(this IEnumerable<string> strings)
    {
        var stringCollection = new StringCollection();
        foreach (string s in strings)
            stringCollection.Add(s);
        return stringCollection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer:

```
Collection<string> collection = new Collection<string>(theList);
```

Comment: Some cases require usage of StringCollection such as clipboard operations